# XSLT 1 - How can I replace '&' with '&amp;' in XML file?

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to find solution to fix by using XSLT 1! Most of sent XML files well formatted and someone make mess by adding characters (& < >. . .).  Any way to do replace this on my side? I tried XSLT 2 and Replace function does not work as I use XSLT processor from Microsoft

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs saxon"
  version="2.0">
<xsl:param name="path" select="'file:///E:/foo.xml'"></xsl:param>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:copy-of select="unparsed-text($path)"></xsl:copy-of>
<xsl:copy-of select="saxon:parse(replace(unparsed-text($path), '&amp;',      '&amp;amp;'))"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any other suggestion how to solve this issue. for example I have input XML file like:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <name>Stack & Exchange</name>
```

And is fail on '&' character.

Please advice!
Thank you

Comment: What's not working about it?

Comment: The `replace()` function can be replaced by a recursive named template. But if your input is not XML, you won't be able to transform it with an XSLT 1.0 processor at all. There is no `unparsed-text()` in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: The input xml is **invalid** whoever passes it to you can not claim to deliver xml - get that fixed.

Comment: Stefan, I know this is INVALID! This is my solution how to validate and fix not well formatted XML files... On received XML files like this replace '&' to &amp;

Comment: @Darius XSLT 1.0 cannot do it; look for another tool (e.g. a text editor).

Comment: @Michael, you talking about manual check. Any different suggestion for automated search?

Comment: No, I'm talking about something you can automate. Don't know what you can use, certainly not on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion

Two observations

- XSLT requires at least a well formed XML document at the input, so I can't use it to correct invalid XML
               (it is an XML transformation language)
- in order to use replace or escape invalid characters of XML on input I need to make sure that I use an XSLT 2.0 processor 
                              (I use Microsoft processor XSLT 1.0)

I see two options

- If I receive an error on input, investigate and validate manually and send back the error message. - THIS IS I TRIED TO AVOID! (Use text tools like notepad++, excel to find an issue).
- write a correcting parser in the .net language to fix before loading as XML